# How do I use PAM with MySQL (on Xenial)?

Tags: mysql, authentication, pam

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and installed `libpam-mysql` and `pamtester`. To test out the module, I tried running the following command:

```
pamtester --item user=X --item passwd=X --item host=127.0.0.1 --item db=X --item table=X --item usercolumn=X --item passwdcolumn=X --item crypt=1 mysql branja authenticate
```

But it always comes back with the error message:

```
pamtester: Unknown item type "passwd"
```

I could assure you that all the connection information I've specified is valid, but the authentication is failing before it even gets that far. I can't seem to find any information about what parameters are required, if not the ones I've given.

---

I also tried putting the following into `/etc/pam.d/mysql`:

```
auth required pam_mysql.so user=X passwd=X host=127.0.0.1 db=X table=X usercolumn=X passwdcolumn=X crypt=1
account sufficient pam_mysql.so user=X passwd=X host=127.0.0.1 db=X table=X usercolumn=X passwdcolumn=X crypt=1
```

But that always results in an authentication failure, presumably for the same reason as the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow.

After browsing through `/var/log/auth.log` and seeing the following message, I have finally figured out that this is due to a bug in the `libpam-mysql` package.

```
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_mysql.so): /lib/security/pam_mysql.so: undefined symbol: make_scrambled_password
PAM adding faulty module: pam_mysql.so
```

A solution, for anyone who's interested, is to uninstall the official `libpam-mysql` and go with [an unofficial package](http://www.dinofly.com/files/linux/libpam-mysql_0.7~RC1-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb) which fixes this bug.

[ [Source](http://ubuntu-bugs.narkive.com/1fqAlWMX/bug-1574900-new-libpam-mysql-undefined-symbol-make-scrambled-password-needs-patches-applied-by) ]